# All of a sudden grub menu started showing

Tags: 16.04, grub2

I have a pure Ubuntu laptop (no dual boot). Today when I restarted, suddenly grub menu started showing. After I select Ubuntu, it boots boots as normal. So my questions are:

1. Why did it start appearing all of a sudden?
2. How do I hide it?

EDIT: output of `cat /etc/default/grub`:

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
#GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="acpi=noirq"
#GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="acpi=force"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""
#GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=force"
#GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi=force"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
#GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi=noirq"

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `cat /etc/default/grub` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 edited the question with the details.

Comment: Run `sudo update-grub` and test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make a small change in your `/etc/default/grub` file to fix this problem.

Open a `terminal` from the Unity dashboard and do the following commands...

- `gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub`
- find the line, near the top of the file, that looks like `GRUB_TIMEOUT=10`
- change `GRUB_TIMEOUT=10` to read `GRUB_TIMEOUT=0`
- save and quit gedit
- `sudo update-grub`
- `reboot`

Comment: Will try and revert shortly.

Comment: That fixed it. Why did it start appearing all of a sudden though?

Comment: @Jus12  A `Software Updater` update may have replaced the `/etc/default/grub` file with a new standard file.